# There exists immersion whose image is a part of a cone?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ intersection of open ball centered at origin and the cone $C=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}; x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2},z\geq 0\}$. Prove there is not immersion $F:U\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ where $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $F(U)=A$.

My idea is that if there existis $F:U\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$  immersion then if $p \in U$ there is a neighboorhood $V$ of $p$ and $F|_{V}:V\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is an embedding then $F(V)$ is an immersed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Am I going the right way?

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: The vertex of the cone is not smooth. If $A$ were a regular surface, near the vertex you could represent the surface by a graph of some smooth function defined in a coordinate plane. However, all three projections are not injective.

Comment: $A$ is the graph of a function @IvoTerek (they consider only $z\ge 0$). The projection to the $x-y$ plane is bijecitve

Comment: Ah. You're correct. But OP can argue that or the last projection is not smooth at the vertex, or its derivative is non-injective (I'd think of $x^2+y^2$ and change of coordinates).